# What does this mean? 1

Tags: questions

According to the gradualist viewpoint, dubbed phyletic gradualism, the origin of novel features, such as the vertebrate eye, can be explained as having arisen from numerous, tiny, imperceptible steps, with each step being advantageous and developed by natural selection

Comment: What puzzles you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of sentence is relatively clear but it could have helped if it had fewer commas. Does the sentence come some standard textbook? The punctuation is certainly redundant. As for the meaning, I would offer this:

> Gradualism says that complex new features like vertebrata eyes have evolved over long time in very small steps, one step at a time. If this  gradual change  proved beneficial, that generation did not perish and it was passed on to the next generation, which underwent its own tiny changes. The complex features  we see now is the  result of these tiny changes over many surviving generations.

In contrast, saltationism believes that these changes came in the shape of sudden big changes